# ionic app run perfectly on browser but not working on devApp and android apk

Tags: ionic-framework

This question is related to `ionic 3` and I want to know how to run an ionic app using a real device.

I have developed an hybrid application and I was not able to connect my app with server. It works fine in my laptop browser. But it does not work in devApp and android apk.

I have tried many solutions but was not able to get the perfect solution. I have made a proxy server to access the api by ionic devApp but it doesn't even show a single error.

I think this problem is related about `CORS`.

Comment: *I have tried many solutions* what did you try? What is the error message? When Chrome Dev Tools say you have a cors problem then it's a cors problem.

Comment: Please tells us the steps you have taken so far.

Answer (score 2):

Use the additional parameter of `--devapp` when running your ionic serve.

```
ionic serve --devapp
```

Should work now.

Answer (score 2):

For me allowing port 8100 in my firewall was needed. Then everythig works.

Answer (score 0):

CORS is not a problem when you build your app on a real device.

To run your app on android device :

1. ionic cordova platform add android
2. ionic cordova build android
3. ionic cordova run android (Connect your device before executing this)

Comment: i am testing it on my android device using  DevApp.still it's not working not even show single error while connecting through real device but it work perfectly on my laptop .

Comment: what is DevApp ?

Comment: it use to test our app on real device

Comment: Did you followed the steps that I mentioned in my answer ?

Comment: Is USB debugging enabled in the device ?

Comment: I am trying to test the app on android mobile using ionic DevApp, and network is wifi (i am not sure if this is the problem, although i have taken the IP from ipconfig and using that - on laptop's browser the app is running fine, but...), also when I try to hit very first login page, the ionic serve -c ---> shows console log and in that i can see the request is being made, but no response - in node api cors module is used and rest of the desktop application is working fine. stuck up with this only.

Comment: you are accessing your app in a browser on mobile ? Why are you taking IP from ipconfig ?

Comment: no, on mobile i am using ionic DevApp to test the app, ipconfig to ensure i am using correct network

Comment: just do one thing, run 'ionic cordova build android', after this go to platforms/android/ and copy the generated .apk file into your device, install it and then run the app

Answer (score 0):

Try Reinstalling cordova-plugin-whitelist plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I'd the same problem.  But I just uninstalled and installed again the ionic DevApp and it solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the command `ionic serve -c` this for view the app into Ionic devApp

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this helps now - In your DevAPp you have settings where you can manually enter IP address and port. This will be the private IP (192.x.x.x) and 8100 that is displayed when you start the ionic serve --devapp from the terminal.